# Android : What's the best way to display an article with images?

Tags: android, listview, webview, article

I'm trying to display an article with paragraphs, images, quotes, etc. My backend currently returns an article as a list of paragraphs, images, etc. but this can be changed if needed.

I tried the following :

- Using a `WebView` and loading the whole article. Works fine but `WebViews` are very consuming and I can't customize content appearance as I would like to.
- Using a `ScrollView` and populating it with `TextViews` for each paragraph and `ImageViews` for each image. Works OK but is very laggy at the beginning while populating the `ScrollView`
- Using a `ListView` (and later a `RecyclerView`) to benefit from recycling. The problem with this solution is that some items may be quite long (ie : a long paragraphe) and it can be laggy when a long item appears on screen while scrolling.

None of the solutions above seems to be optimal, so I wonder : what's the best way to display an article?

Thanks for your answers

**Edit 2:**
All the solutions above **work**, my question is not about how to make it work but about how to make it as **optimized** and **smooth** as possible.

**Edit:** This is the kind of things I'm trying to display.

[image]

Comment: I would still recommend going for RecyclerView, you will just have to truncate long articles and add the details screen for the whole article

Comment: @Chaosit I'm not talking about a list of articles but about the content of one single article!

Comment: I'm sorry I've misunderstood the question, in this case if it is possible to isolate separate parts of article (like "chapters") I would use two-level RecyclerView - top level will contain the name of the section and after user clicks on the name field - you should expand the content part of the section

Comment: If such isolation is impossible the only solution I can see is a WebView

Comment: ok, now I can see the screenshot of what you want to show, I still think that WebView is better to show such long pages, the problem is that mobile apps are usually not designed for displaying such long pages. Alternative solution I can think of is using the ViewPager (or some paginated vertically scrolled element), but in this case you will have to figure out how to add pagination to the article - and it looks like it's possible to do that

Comment: @Chaosit Thanks. I like your solution with the `ViewPager`, it could definitely make everything smoother. Unfortunately, I think reading an article with this kind of vertical pagination is not as comfortable as a regular `ListView`/`ScrollView`... If you have another solution, I'll take it!

Comment: sorry that was my last idea =), perhaps the use of your own custom subclassed `ScrollView` implementing rendering of additional views as soon as user scrolls for instance 75% of current scroll distance may work, but in this case the scrollbar will behave really weird from user's point of view(like reaching 75% of distance and then jumping back to 50)

Comment: use the method Html.fromHtml(String , ImageGetter, TagHandler), this way you can use an html like string to display a well formatted article inside a single TextView

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView is the best practice. It has the best optimization.